# viewpager fixed to top of activity when listview scrolled

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

i have a viewpager and listview in one activity . and viewpager is top of list view but when i scroll down to see all listview , viewpager is fixed in top activity . 
i want viewpager scrolled too and when i scroll up viewpager shown .

this is my xml and i have a simple viewpager adapter .

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/frame"

        android:background="@color/list_background"
        >

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"


            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@drawable/drawer_selector"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/kaghaz"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:background="@drawable/kaghaz"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/now"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical"

            >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_above="@id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />


    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:background="@color/list_background"/>
```

Comment: i think , i should use another component like view pager . i used that before but i forget that

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ScrollView, give ListView and ViewPager as children.

Comment: Using `ListVew` inside `ScrollView` is not recommended practice. `ListView` has its own scrolling and it doesn't receive inputs by default because they are handled by the parent `ScrollView`

Comment: Can you try adding the ViewPager as header than(by using addHeaderView method of listview)?